# slideToggle a div above a transitioning div

Tags: jquery, html, transition, layer, slidetoggle

I'm trying to slideToggle a normal div box into a div that uses the transition effect when hovered over (basically, there are two pictures in a container, both at the exact same spot, and if the picture on top is hovered it will smoothly disappear and appear just as smooth again when the mouse is gone).
[Demo](http://liveweave.com/cmx1Bn)

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#scrolldown 
  {background-color:#000000;width:90%;height:10%;}
#blend 
  {position: absolute;top:10%;}
#blend img
  {opacity:0;position: absolute; 
   top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 1;    
   transition: opacity 0.5s;}
#top:hover 
  {opacity:0}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>CLICK</h1>

    <div id="scrolldown"></div>
    <div id="blend">
    <img src="hover.png">
    <img id="top" src="default.png">
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#scrolldown").hide();

  $("h1").click(function() {
    $("#scrolldown").slideToggle(1000);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I want to achieve, that the toggling container (black) is displayed above the transitioning one (red). I've tryed giving the black container a z-index of 2, while giving the red one a z-index of 1, but there's no change still, putting the boxes into different layers with different z-indexes doesn't help out aswell.
After trying out various numbers, I realized, using -1 as a z-index for the red box actually makes the black box appear above it, however the transition effect doesn't work anymore.
([Demo](http://liveweave.com/be9hZz)) (I suspect this is because the transition is dependent on having different layers).
Does anybody have another idea?

Comment: Post your code for people to help with

Comment: @AndyHolmes Excuse me, what exactly do you mean? Have I messed up with the "Demo" Hyperlinks? In that case, here are the direct links:
  http://liveweave.com/cmx1Bn  
http://liveweave.com/be9hZz
I'm sorry, but I couldn't get it working with jsfiddle, for some reason it doesn't want to run my jQuery script, even tough I've activated it on Frameworks & Extensions. But I think lineweave does the job just as good.

Comment: No i literally mean add your code to the question. Adding a link is great bonus but adding the code will be better. Some people can read your code and find the issue without the need for a link

Comment: Alright, updated, thank you for giving me hints on what to do better, that is really appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want is this: even if the black box is above the red one, hovering the region of the black box that is right above the red one must make the first red image disappear smoothly?

Comment: Not exactly, sorry for being so unclear. The black box only slides up and down, each time you click it. There's nothing more it should do. The red box is smoothly changing the color of itself. The problem is, when the black box displays above the red one, the transition effect (on the red box) doesn't work. It doesn't matter if the transition effect works when you hover the region of the black box that is right above the red one, clou is, the transition effect works, even when the black box is above the red one.